# Visual Studio Online continuous integration and Compass

Tags: ruby, continuous-integration, compass-sass, azure-devops

I've created a continuous build for an angular project in Visual Studio Online but I ran into a problem.

In order to run the grunt task for SASS I need to install Compass which needs Ruby to run.

Does anyone have any experience getting ruby to run on a VSO build agent?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't install Ruby on a hosted build agent.

The following link lists all software which are installed on hosted build server (Ruby is not listed). Also, you are not allowed to install any software on hosted build server.

As a workaround, you can install your desire software on on-premises build agents and control them using an on-premises build controller.

Please check the following links for the detailed reference about how to setup build controller and build agent:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee330987.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb399135.aspx